# Django error on set cookie, test_cookie is false

Tags: django, firebug

Problem solved!
Sorry I did not mention that I am using `dotcloud`. It is due to the git of dotcloud. Projects on dotcloud need a `postinstall` to run scripts, but with its build-in git, it will ignore the executable bit. So I follow the url [Warning: postinstall file exists, but it is not executable. Ignoring.](http://answers.dotcloud.com/question/436/warning-postinstall-file-exists-but-it-is-not). and upload total file in my project again. Problem solved. I think it is because I do not create the session database.
But there still a question. The default session do not use database as a back end right? Even if it using a back end, my project's back end is MongoDB, which has a lazy operation method, I mean it will create the database when it is been used. So why without `syncdb`, it could cause this problem?

I'm using `response.set_cookie` to set cookies. But it can not be shown on `firefox`'s `firebug`.

I've tried `request.session.set_test_cookie()`, but it shows that my browser do not support cookie. That's impossible. I also tried `Safari`, also can not set cookie.

How's that happen? I am sure my browser support cookie, I could see cookies send back from other sites by `firebug`.

The code is as following:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = request.POST.get('password','')

```
if username != '' and password != '':
    if len(username) > 20:
        returnmsg = 'USR LEN'

    else:
        password = md5(password).hexdigest()
        user_exist = User.objects(username=username)
        if not user_exist:  #if the list is empty
            returnmsg = 'LOG ERR'
        else:
            for user in User.objects(username=username):
                if user.password == password:
                    returnmsg = 'LOG OK'
                    #add session information
                    response = HttpResponse(returnmsg)
```

`#Try 1`

```
                response['Cookie-Set']='username='+username
```

`#try 2`

```
                response.set_cookie(key="username", value=username)
```

`#try 3`

```
                request.session['username'] = username

                    user.log.append(UserLog(time=datetime.now(), ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], login=True))
                    user.save()
                    return response
                else:
                    returnmsg = 'LOG ERR'
                    user.log.append(UserLog(time=datetime.now(), ip=request.META['REMOTE_ADDR'], login=False))
                    user.save()
else:
    returnmsg = 'USR EPT'
```

Comment: already added. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: So firebug's Net console does not show set-cookie header? Isn't there any webserver which do not allow headers to pass through it?